# Use OAuth2 or JWT for mobile application with Wordpress backend (REST API)

Tags: wordpress, react-native, oauth-2.0, jwt, wordpress-rest-api

So.. I've read countless articles, but still can't wrap my mind on which to use; if a simple JSON Web Token is enough..

I have a Wordpress website and a mobile application of said website.
I can login in my website using email and password and I can also login on my mobile application using email and password.
The mobile application communicates with the website through the Wordpress REST API. It (the mobile app) sends the user email and password to the API, and the API returns a JWT if both are valid.
Then, I simply store the JWT in the user's device.

My main doubts are:
**For a mobile app with not much sensitive user data, is that acceptable/safe enough?**
**For a mobile app with sensitive user data, is that acceptable/safe enough?**

Or should I use OAuth2 in both cases (which is harder to implement and will take time, but it's safer (I think..))?
Thank you and apologies if duplicated.

Comment: Its not clear to me that- when you have an auth api, which you are calling from the mobile app, then where exactly are you planning to use Oauth?

Comment: hey @variable! So, yeah, I eventually ended up using just a JWT since I just wanted to log the user in; OAuth would probably be way overkill for such case (and maybe even pointless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a security compliance decision you might have to take.

As a first thing, you should think like a product owner or ask a product owner about which one to use by explaining to them, what are the advantages of OAuth 2.0 over simple JWT.

You might have to consider the following things,

1. what is the size of the userbase?
2. how sensitive is the data you are going to store?
3. What is the user experience you wanted to give to your users?

Also, JWT doesn't mean it is not safe enough.

One more extra thing you could do to make it more secure is adding a expiry time for your JWT with a refresh token mechanism that way even if JWT is exposed it ll be expired later sometime.

Comment: For a native app with no sensitive data I'm just using a JWT with an expiration date (haven't decided how long it should last yet..), but for a native app with sensitive data I'm still not sure how to proceed.. should it have a login page? Should it have a separate server just for authentication (with its own login page, so the app wouldn't have a login screen itself, it would open a browser).. then store a refresh and access token on the user device? Am I over engineering this? :(

Comment: This blog can help you understand more. https://hashedin.com/blog/auth-headers-vs-jwt-vs-sessions-choosing-right-auth-technique-for-apis/

Comment: Thank you senthil :)

Comment: Where can the OP use Oauth in the described scenario? All he has is an WordPress api that returns jwt.

Answer (score 0):

JWT is a secure solution and is often used for mobile applications.

If you choose OAuth, you have several options for authentication, because there are several grant types:

- Authorization Code grant type, which is the most popular, the advantage of this is that it uses the WordPress login interface
- User Credentials grant type, which has a direct trust relationship with the application, which provides the user credentials, this is often used with mobile applications

You have the option of JWT Access Tokens at the OAuth server, which provides even more security for you.

We have created an OAuth 2.0 plugin for WordPress: https://lana.codes/product/lana-passport/

You can try it with the demo, and there is also detailed documentation for it.

I personally use the OAuth plugin to be able to log in to my WordPress websites using the Single Sign On button, which uses my primary WordPress website for authentication. OAuth is more commonly used for Single Sign On solutions.